# If i delete a file from a project using git, does it get restored if I go back to an earlier commit?

Tags: git

For instance I have asp.net mvc project and an AdminController.cs plus an AdministrationController.cs, if I delete one, and i later decide I want to look at what i wrote can i revert to that commit and the file gets restored?

Comment: ... yes... provided that you added and committed the file before deleting it.

Comment: @martin jakubik Ah I probably only added but didn't commit it.

Comment: Everything you **committed** in the past is stored in the repo and is accessible using Git commands.

Comment: Yes. And note that you don't need to revert the commit to see the old file, you can checkout that old commit to view it without adding new changes to your history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it gets restored if you did git add and git commit on the file.

Let's try it. Note that in the example below we have two locations:

- the local workspace (this is just your filesystem)
- the git repository (this is the history of your files once added to git)

Create a new git repository and create two files in the local workspace:

```
user1> git init use-git
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/user1/gitwork/use-git/.git/

user1> cd use-git/

user1> echo "code" > AdminController.cs

user1> echo "code" > AdministrationController.cs

user1> ls
AdminController.cs          AdministrationController.cs
```

Add the two files that are in the local workspace to the git repository:

```
user1> git add AdminController.cs AdministrationController.cs

user1> git commit -m"added two Admin controllers"
[master (root-commit) 8f03b8e] added two Admin controllers
 2 files changed, 2 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 AdminController.cs
 create mode 100644 AdministrationController.cs

user1> ls
AdminController.cs          AdministrationController.cs
```

Remove one of the files from the local workspace:

```
user1> git rm AdminController.cs
rm 'AdminController.cs'

user1> ls
AdministrationController.cs
```

Use git commit to remove the file from the git repository:

```
user1> git commit -m"removed a redundant Admin controller"
[master 8bff415] removed a redundant Admin controller
 1 file changed, 1 deletion(-)
 delete mode 100644 AdminController.cs

user1> ls
AdministrationController.cs
```

Look at the git log and find the previous change:

```
user1> git log
commit 8bff4159f0bafb187197c148608228a41d0d55ae
...
    removed a redundant Admin controller
commit 8f03b8e0e098c85e03c91a84b8315581a2a4c5ac
...
    added two Admin controllers
```

Go back to the previous change:

```
user1> git checkout 8f03b8e0e098c85e03c91a84b8315581a2a4c5ac
Note: checking out '8f03b8e0e098c85e03c91a84b8315581a2a4c5ac'.
...
You are in 'detached HEAD' state.
...
HEAD is now at 8f03b8e... added two Admin controllers
```

Note that the file you deleted is still available for you to look at:

```
user1> ls
AdminController.cs          AdministrationController.cs

user1> cat AdminController.cs
code
```

Comment: Is using rm file the same thing as deleting a file, right click->delete, and then commiting that? I was already assuming that using git commands to add and rm files would be preserved, my question was therefore about deleteing the file not using git rm.

Comment: Well, just using git add or git rm does not preserve the files. To preserve a file you need to git add then git commit. After that, if you right click delete or git rm, you can still get it back.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, the files are restored**. And it will be even easier if you have some kind of good IDE that supports `Git`, also remember you have to have your files added and committed before deleting them as mentioned by @martin in the comment above.

Answer (score 0):

You can either check in your commit history to compare the files, or you can cherry pick the commit with "git cherry-pick your_commit_hash" and restore your deleted files.